# Selenium web driver in a web application get user inputs

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web application hosted on a web server that uses selenium web driver to do some action on web sites and save that response for the user to see at the end.
Right now this works fine, the user uploads the data to search for and the application runs on the server, opening chrome windows to navigate on the sites.

The issue is that , there is a site that need user input to continue. Is there a way to instead of opening the chrome window on the server, I open it on the clients machine? In a way that I could control the flow of this new page, wait for the user to take action, and then continue to perform the automated action.

Any option would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: As part of your "upload the data to search for" can you also include the response that they will need on that particular page?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://url.here")`

Then you can use a something like

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));

if (driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("selector")).Displayed)
    {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.CssSelector("selector")));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("selector")).SendKeys("text you want entered");
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("selector")).Click(); //There are other properties and methods you can access
    }
```

Comment: But this would run in the server. What I need is a way that the web application open the Chromedriver on the users machine so he can type some information, and the test continues from there.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. Generally Selenium is used for automating the tasks rather than expecting human interaction. I think what you might want to do is add a wait which is like a pause. This will give the user time to enter info, then you process the action after that wait is released.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking into a way to have human interaction also.